# General error;383 invalid identifier: RESB: on inner join

Tags: sql, sap-erp

I'm trying to inner join Materials (`MATNR`) from the `MARC` table to the `RESB` table but I always get the error:

> General error;383 Invalid Identifier: RESB

The line with the error:

```
"MARC"."MATNR" = "RESB"."MATNR" AND
```

Here is the full code:

```
select 
"RESB"."MATNR" as "Material",
"RESB"."BDMNG" as "Quantidade",
"RESB"."MEINS" as "Unit",
"RESB"."BDTER" as "Data da reserva",
"RESB"."RSNUM" as "Reserva",
"RESB"."RSPOS" as "Item da Reserva",
"RESB"."AUFNR" as "Ordem",
"RESB"."WERKS" as "Centro"

from "RBT_SLT_ECC"."RESB"

union

select
"MSEG"."DMBTR" as "Custo"

from "RBT_SLT_ECC"."MSEG"

inner join 
"RBT_SLT_ECC"."MARC" on 
"MARC"."MATNR" = "RESB"."MATNR" AND 
"MARC"."WERKS" = "RESB"."WERKS"

where
"RESB"."WERKS" in ('1402')

order by
"RESB"."BDTER" DESC
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `Resb` doesn't exist in the select-query after the union, so it doesn't know about `resb`. Note that the amount of columns differs before and after the union as well, but thats another issue.

Comment: How can I fix it?

Comment: I don't know the full definition of the tables or what youre trying to do. I can only assume, and that is to try to get rid of the `union` and start from `RESB` and join both `MSEG` and `MARC`.

Comment: @EduardoFF . . . Add it to the `FROM` clause.